# How to use noexcept in assignment operator with copy-and-swap idiom?

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept, copy-and-swap

The move assignment operator should often be declared noexcept (i.e. to store the type in STL containers). But the copy-and-swap idiom allows both copy- and move- assignment operators to be defined in a single piece of code. What to do with noexcept specifier in this case? The copy construction can throw, but I doubt whether it can violate the noexcept specifier.

```
// Is it correct considering that T copy constructor can throw?
T& operator=(T other) noexcept;
```

Comment: The `noexcept` here is fine. Note that the `is_nothrow_*_constructible` traits will still return the correct value because they're implemented similar to `noexcept(declval<T&>() = declval<T const&>())` which also takes into account whether the copy or move constructor throws (because that copy/move needs to happen to pass by value).

Comment: You may also be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7458222/576911 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18303787/576911

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the copy is made **on the *caller's* side** of the call, it is not part of what your function does. It can therefore not be controlled by your function and consequently, you can not include this information in the `noexcept` specification.

The only thing you could do is to play it safe and add *both* options to your `noexcept` specification. Of course, that means you are getting some false-negatives.

Comment: Do you mean that exception thrown in copy constructor while passing py value to a function is not a part of this function, so it can be safely declared as noexcept?

Comment: @lizarisk "Safely" is a strong word. Basically, I'd say yes to that. The problem is that the **caller** must be aware of what it requires for his own `noexcept` specification. But then, from your perspective it's a SEP (somebody else's problem).

Comment: I'd answer that with "yes it is safe" as in "is correct" IFF the body does indeed not throw (which is the case for a swap). Example code proving this: https://godbolt.org/z/bzLOGA. Note how the traits `is_nothrow_*` still return the correct values.

Answer (score 10):

As usual, [Daniel Frey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073257/daniel-frey) is [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18848460/1137388). All I want is showing a piece of code that illustrates the point.

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {

    foo() = default;

    foo(const foo&) {
        std::cout << "throw\n";
        throw 1;
    }

    foo& operator =(foo) noexcept {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {

    foo f, g;
    try {
        f = g; // throws
    }
    catch(int) {
        std::cout << "catch\n";
    }
}
```

When compiled with gcc 4.8.1 (`-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) it gives no warnings. Running the code produces the following output:

```
throw
catch
```

Therefore, the copy constructor does throw when called but that's no considered inside `operator =()` and, therefore, the `noexcept` promise was fulfilled. Otherwise, terminate would be called before `catch` could be printed out.

Comment: May I suggest to revise the code to this and include a link: https://godbolt.org/z/bzLOGA