# Rule of 4.5: No move assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Based on the popular question [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/):

1. Why does the rule of 4.5 not include the move assignment operator (to effectively become the rule of 5.5)? Instead I've read (eg. here [What is the Rule of Four (and a half)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754226/)) that we either have rule of 4.5 or 5?
2. Since the `swap` member function is `noexcept`, shouldnt the copy assignment operator also be marked the same (the move constructor can't since it calls the default constructor that can throw)?

```
dumb_array& operator=(dumb_array other) // should be noexcept?
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it would not be useful.

Click your second link then forth link there [The Rule of The Big Four (and a half) – Move Semantics and Resource Management](https://blog.feabhas.com/2015/01/the-rule-of-the-big-four-and-a-half-move-semantics-and-resource-management/)

Read carefully section **5 – Move assignment**.

You will see

> Eliminating the move assignment operator
>
> In reality is the move assignment operator is unnecessary!

with all the explanation!

**Essentially the operator `dumb_array& operator=(dumb_array other)` will be used when normally you would have used move assignment operator.**

I haven't verified but you might be able to delete it too as it will not be generated anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also clarify the second  question about making the copy assignment noexcept?

Comment: `noexcept` should not be there. `dumb_array other` constructs a copy or moves an object depending on lvalue or rvalue passed. Both are not noexcept.